# How to select not exists data in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis

i dived into SSIS because of curiosity, what i want to do is inserting "Not Exists" Data to postgresql. i want to select "Not Exists" data from  Postgresql which is joined to the data selected from Mssql, and insert into Postgresql. Below is the Data Flow Task.

Sorry for my English, i hope you got i what i want to do.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "Not Exists."  Do you mean you want to copy records which exist in the Postgres database, but do not exist in the MS SQL database?  The kind of thing for which you'd use an `EXCEPT` operator?

Comment: i want to select records which are not exists in postgresql but exists in mssql, and i will insert them in to postgresql, i am trying to create a SSIS package then i will deploy it to MSSQL server and job scheduler will do the rest, the thing is i can not write my own query this is not an option in SSIS tools

Comment: There is like 10 different ways of doing that. You need to describe, if the data are being changed only in MSSQL, if you can change schema in MSSQL. One of the simpler solutions would be to use timestamps or CDC in SQL Server.

Comment: Data changes only in Mssql, i could use timestamps but how?

Comment: @washaq one thing at a time.  It sounds like you're trying to do three things: #1 is pulling a set of records from MS SQL; #2 is subtracting from that records which already exist in PostgreSQL; #3 is inserting the resulting set into PostgreSQL.  Is that right?  If so, focus on #1 first.  Can you pull the full set of MS SQL records?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Yes, You are right, this is what i want to do. i can pull the full set of MS SQL and PostgreSQL records and without any condition i can insert into defined Destination. But i want to compare both sources and find if MS SQL has any records which PostgreSQL does not have.

Answer (score 1):

i achieved by following this post; 
[How to get unmatched data between two sources in SSIS Data Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50681730/2429054)

and here is my screen shot;

[image]

by doing this, i am joining 2 different sources and splitting unmatched data than i insert into destination.

i appreciate your efforts. Thank you so much.